# ArcGIS Workflow Manager - How to setup a query to display current step?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-workflow-manager

I'd like to setup a query that shows the current step as one of the fields in the results window.  For example, we have a query that shows all jobs in the system.  The challenge for me is since "step" is not one of the fields in the main jobs table, it has to be retrieved thru an intermediary table(s).  I'm not sure how to create a query that would include this field in the display. Using v10.2.  Another way to ask my question is how do I display a field that is not in the main jobs table, in the results view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out using some existing queries as a guide.  This is tough to answer given the proprietary nature of queries but basically you have to include, in your query, the tables and fields that you want to display. The "Where" statement is where I was having issues and you have to setup links between the primary table and the secondary table you want to display. Something like `TableA.Field1=TableB.Field1 AND TableB.Field2=TableC.Field2`.

Comment: Please add additional details so that future readers will be able to benefit from the question too.

Comment: Thanks @Steve.  I have included your comments in the answer.